# SQL Concatenation with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

When executing below sql query,not getting out put as expected.Pl correct me.

```
SELECT              
COALESCE(NULLIF(b1.ShortCode,NULL)+'|'+ NULLIF(b2.ShortCode,NULL)+'|'+ 
NULLIF(b3.ShortCode,NULL)+'|'+ 
NULLIF(b4.ShortCode,NULL),NULLIF(b5.ShortCode,NULL))as Result
FROM tbl_PropertyDetails                                
LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b1 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member1ID = b1.FMID
LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b2 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member2ID = b2.FMID
LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b3 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member3ID = b3.FMID
LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b4 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member4ID = b4.FMID
LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b5 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member5ID = b5.FMID
[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the output you want it to be? Otherwise we can't solve the question

Comment: could you please tell what is the actual result and what result you want and also table description.?

Comment: At least you need to describe the expected output and how it differs from what you get.

Comment: string concat null => null.

Comment: `NULLIF(x,NULL)` Is redundant - it will return `NULL` only if `x` is `NULL` - So everywhere you have `NULLIF(x,NULL)` you can simply use `x` instead

Comment: The SQL concatenation operator is `||` not `+`. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the equivalent of `CONCAT_WS()` . . . putting the `|` only between actual values.  If so:

```
SELECT STUFF( COALESCE('|' + b1.ShortCode, '') + 
              COALESCE('|' + b2.ShortCode, '') + 
              COALESCE('|' + b3.ShortCode, '') + 
              COALESCE('|' + b4.ShortCode, '') + 
              COALESCE('|' + b5.ShortCode, ''),
              1, 1, '') as Result
FROM tbl_PropertyDetails LEFT JOIN
     tbl_FamilyMember b1
     ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member1ID = b1.FMID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_FamilyMember b2
     ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member2ID = b2.FMID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_FamilyMember b3
     ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member3ID = b3.FMID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_FamilyMember b4
     ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member4ID = b4.FMID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_FamilyMember b5
     ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member5ID = b5.FMID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(b1.ShortCode, '') + '|' + COALESCE(b2.ShortCode, '') + '|'
        + COALESCE(b3.ShortCode, '') + '|' + COALESCE(b4.ShortCode, '') ,
        COALESCE(b5.ShortCode, '') AS Result
FROM    tbl_PropertyDetails
        LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b1 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member1ID = b1.FMID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b2 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member2ID = b2.FMID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b3 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member3ID = b3.FMID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b4 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member4ID = b4.FMID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_FamilyMember b5 ON tbl_PropertyDetails.Member5ID = b5.FMID
```